# TCL extract some output

Tags: split, tcl

That i want to do is to separate reason and handle on some variables.
Example:
That's one row in my list.txt
Where:

```
example row: *!*~*@217.21.146.130 someone Tachka, kakvo stava proshlqk? 0
someone = handle
*!*~*@217.21.146.130 someone Tachka, kakvo stava proshlqk? 0 = reason
```

May be somethig like:

```
[foreach line [split [readfile blacklist.txt] \n] {set reason [lrange $list 2 end-1]}]
```

Comment: So within the reason, there is also the handle? It would be good I think if you could clarify your question. As it is, I find it quite confusing. I would have said that the handle would be `*!*~*@217.21.146.130` and the reason `someone Tachka, kakvo stava proshlqk? 0` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming** that you want to put `someone` as the value for the `handle` variable, and that the `reason` variable should hold `Tachka, kakvo stava proshlqk? 0`

```
set fh [open blacklist.txt r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    set reason [lassign [split $line] ip handle]
    puts "handle = $handle"
    puts "reason = [join $reason]"
}
close $fh
```

---

You have:

```
# Blacklist File:
set blackl(file) "scripts/blacklist.txt"

### CIDR
proc bl:cidr:ban {nick uhost hand chan} {
    global botnick exempt_userflag
    set fh [open blackl(file) r]
```

you need:

```
proc bl:cidr:ban {nick uhost hand chan} {
    global botnick exempt_userflag blackl
    set fh [open $blackl(file) r]
```

---

Given the updated requirement:

```
set line {*!*~*@217.21.146.130 someone Tachka, kakvo stava proshlqk? 0}
set rest [lassign [split $line] ip handle]
set reason [join [lrange $rest 0 end-1]]
set timeout [lindex $rest end]
```

Comment: i've tried on this way but wont work gives me that "Tcl error [bl:cidr:ban]: invalid command name "blackl(file)": http://paste.tclhelp.net/?id=f6e

Comment: Here the result P.S 0 should not appear 0 = time for ban: http://pastebin.com/ypbgxBpz

Comment: next time, work on specifying your requirements much more clearly. If you have any additional questions, please edit your question and ask them there instead of hiding them in comments.

Comment: But don't just edit a question to add unrelated questions; make them be _new_ Stack Overflow Questions. The purpose of editing is to clarify the question you've already asked.